# Finding index funtion returns zero (0) Matlab

Tags: matlab, indexing, match

I use this function in matlab to find the index of two values in matrix A matching two values in matrix B:

```
[~, ind] = ismember(A(:, [1 2]), B(:, [1 2]), 'rows');
```

However, i get some values 0 returned as output.

Does this mean that certain pairs of values in matrix B are not present in matrix A?

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html)? This is very well explained in the documentation with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the documentation part, MATLAB is very rich in documentation. Check the below example:

```
A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 -9 0] ;
B = [3 4 5 ; 1 2 3 ] ;
[Lia, Locb] = ismember(A,B, 'rows') 
Lia =

     1
     0
     0

Locb =

     2
     0
     0
```

The result, Lia is logical and Locb is double. Lia gives logical indices in A which are common rows in A and B. (In the example the first row in A [1 2 3], is common), so the logical indices would be [1 0 0]'. Locb gives the indices/ location of common rows in B. (Here common row [ 1 2 3], this occurs in B at second row) so the result [2  0 0]'.

In your case, you said the result *ind* are zeroes, so there are no common rows.